# nginx map regexp for Magento MAGE_RUN_TYPE based on nginx $http_host and $uri

Tags: nginx, magento

I'm trying to write a nginx config that adds a custom header and pass a variable using fastcgi_param based on two variables that are calculated using map, based on $uri and $http_host.

```
map $uri $STORE_LANGUAGE {
    ~^/products en;
    ~^/de/produkte de;
    ~^/fr/produits fr;
    ~^/hu/termekek hu;
}
map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    www.example.com example_com_;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    add_header mage-run-code $MAGE_RUN_CODE$STORE_LANGUAGE;
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE$STORE_LANGUAGE;
       fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
}
```

The goal is to be able to pass the mage-run-code to Magento 2.2 via fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE (and have the header as an easy way to debug for now). This way Magento knows which store view to serve the visitor.

The above code works for www.example.com/products. (Expected behaviour: example_com_en)

What do I have to change in the regexp for STORE_LANGUAGE in order for www.example.com/products/tshirt.html to work as well?

EDIT:
For www.example.com/products $MAGE_RUN_CODE is calculated correctly ("example_com_") as is $STORE_LANGUAGE ("en") resulting in "example_com_en".

For www.example.com/products/tshirt.html $MAGE_RUN_CODE is calculated correctly (based on $http_host). But $STORE_LANGUAGE returns empty. Thus the combination of $MAGE_RUN_CODE$STORE_LANGUAGE is "example_com_" and not the expected "example_com_en" for the tshirt.html URL.

Comment: are you saying that when accessing www.example.com/products the mapping working fine but when access  www.example.com/products/tshirt.html it not works? the header mage-run-code not shown or the $store_language is false? Please explain more. When i see the regex in map block its should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Ilham Sulaksono. I tried to clarify my question with an edit.

Comment: wow, that's a strange behavior. I test it with my own nginx, and it work well. I think the error is not in the regex

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me know that. I will retest everything on Monday and come back with my findings.